# Web Audio API analyser не выдаёт данные об аудио

Tags: javascript, web-audio

Есть такой код сделанный по документации и мануалам, схема: источник -> аналайзер -> вывод.
В консоли выводит пустые значения:
[-90, -90, -90, -90, -90…]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0…]
[128, 128, 128, 128, 128…]
Пробовал цеплять промежуточные узлы - они работают нормально. В чём может быть проблема с аналайзером?

```
//get audio element
stream = $('#audio-source').get(0);

//WebAudio API
var context = new AudioContext();

//Input/Output
var source = context.createMediaElementSource(stream);
var output = context.destination;

//Analyser
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = 1024;

//Create Arrays for data
fFrequencyData = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
bFrequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
bTimeData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

//Get Data
analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(fFrequencyData);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(bFrequencyData);
analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(bTimeData);

//Nodes Commutation
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(output);

console.log(fFrequencyData);
console.log(bFrequencyData);
console.log(bTimeData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true },
      function(stream) {
  aCtx = new AudioContext();
  analyser = aCtx.createAnalyser();
        microphone = aCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphone.connect(analyser);
  
        analyser.connect(aCtx.destination);
  console.log('start');
  analyser.fftSize = 2048;
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
fFrequencyData = new Float32Array(bufferLength);
bFrequencyData = new Uint8Array(bufferLength); 
bTimeData = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);


function draw() {
requestAnimationFrame(draw);     //цикл
analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(fFrequencyData); 
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(bFrequencyData); 
analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(bTimeData);

   console.log(fFrequencyData);
   console.log(bFrequencyData);
   console.log(bTimeData);
    };
//
draw();
    
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
};
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.